# How to write to block memory?

Tags: fpga, serial, memory, rs232

I need to write 16x16 bit data to block memory. I am using RS232 to send data. To get 16 bit data, I send 2x8bit. Now, how can I write my data to the memory?

I have a write signal and 16 bit input but I do not know what I shoul do next.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it is to implement something like a UART receiver section that can collect the serial data into an 8 bit register, and a small state machine that can take complete bytes and build the 16 bit words from them, and then store them into the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need some higher level protocol for framing/packetization.  Once you know which bytes need to go where, store them in registers as they come in.  Once both the high and low bytes for each memory location are in registers, write them into the block RAM.  Repeat for subsequent bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with alex about framing. This can easily become complex, and then a solution may be the timing of the data sent. If you have a long pause between bursts you can use that to reset a RAM pointer. Use the FPGA's clock to downcount a register (width depends on clock speed and pause length). If the register reaches zero then reset the RAM pointer. Use a flipflop to determine whether to write the LOB or the HOB to a temporary register at the stop bit. Toggle the FF at each received byte. If the second byte of each 16-bit word is received copy to the RAM position the pointer points to, and increment the pointer.